# jShowOff not showing numeric links, shows 'undefined' instead

Tags: jquery

I made a content rotator with jShowOff in a wordpress site, and wanted to have numeric links to each slide, that normaly comes by default but somehow shows 'undefined', the only thing i found on the internet was that it has problems with jQuery under 1.6, and i believe wordpress has way above that.... tried a workaround by making a counter and giving each slide that title, but then it pops the number as a title, not just looking ugly but also like a bug...any help? Here's the code for the example:

```
<div id="recentes">
                <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=oficiais&posts_per_page=7');
                    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
                    <div><p>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('recent-thumbnail',array('title' => "")); ?>
                    <span class="recentes_tit"><?php the_title(); ?></span><br /><p><?php $myExcerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                    $tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
                    $myExcerpt = str_replace($tags, "", $myExcerpt);
                    $myExcerpt = str_replace("<br />", " ", $myExcerpt);
                    echo $myExcerpt;
                    ?></p class="content_readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Ver artigo</a></p></div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#recentes").jshowoff({
                        autoPlay:true,
                        changeSpeed:1500,
                        controls:true,
                        effect:"slideLeft",
                        hoverPause:true,
                        speed:4500,
                    }); });
    </script>
```